# How to specify exactly what command caused an exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I was wondering, is it possible to catch and exception and print out exaclty which command made the exception. I know I can do it if I serround every command or split the exception into parts. but I was wondering if I can make 1 big try/catch and print out the exact command that caused the exception.

For example, this is a part of my code:

```
try{
        if(da.StartBlngConnection() == null)
            return handler.generateUpdateStatusResponse(request, "got exception in npUpdateStatus" , "ERROR", "6084");

        System.out.println(request.getNpgRequestId() + " - " + LOG_TAG + "- RequestReceived:\n\n" + requestWrapper.toString());

        da.DBLog("npUpdateStatus(Requst)", new Date(), requestWrapper.toString(), request.getNpgRequestId() , request.getOldOperator(), request.getNewOperator(), "" ,"", "");
        response = handler.handleUpdateStatus(request);
        responseWrapper = new com.tzar.wrappers.UpdateStatusResponseWrapper(response);
        da.DBLog("npUpdateStatus(Response)", new Date(), responseWrapper.toString(), request.getNpgRequestId() , request.getOldOperator(), request.getNewOperator(), response.getMessageStatus().getRequestStatus() + " :" + response.getMessageStatus().getRequestReasonMessage(), "", ""); //
        return response;
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
        System.out.println( request.getNpgRequestId() + " - " + LOG_TAG +" GotException: " + e);
        da.DBLog("npUpdateStatus(Exception)", new Date(), requestWrapper.toString(), request.getNpgRequestId() , request.getOldOperator(), request.getNewOperator(), MakeSureNotOutOfRange(e.toString(),4000) ,"", "");
        return handler.generateUpdateStatusResponse(request, "got exception in npUpdateStatus" , "ERROR", "");
    }
```

I have had a null pointer exception, but I had to debug it to find out where it happend, I want it to point out exactly where it happend.

TY

Comment: That is what the *stack trace* tells you.

Comment: but i do not print the stacktrace , i am printing logs to my DB

Comment: You should print the stack-trace to your log ;)

Comment: are you sure that's the only way, because sometimes the stacktrace is very large

Comment: All of that information is potentially useful, it tells you the context that the exception occurred in.  If you want to truncate the trace, then you can iterate over it using `getStackTrace()`.

Comment: Well yes but it's an exception, so you shouldn't get that many of them. Especially null pointer exceptions as that indicates a bug you should deal with.

Answer (score 2):

```
catch(Exception e) {
     // do stuff...
     e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

That will tell you exactly what line it was on. It will print to `System.err`. If you want it to print to a file or something just change `System.err` to a writer to your file.

You could also try:

```
catch(Exception e) {
     // do stuff...
     for (StackTraceElement el : e.getStackTrace()) {
         // do stuff with the element (i.e. send to log)
     }
}
```

[Here are the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) for a `StackTraceElement`.

Comment: But When i Use e.printStackTrace() the IDE hits(i am using netbeans) tells me stright on e.printStackTrace should be removed..

Comment: and lets say i want to add the entire stacktrace to my DB , how can i do that? i am not going to loop trought it all...

Comment: because it doesnt feel like the right way to go... i want to store the stacktrace as a string at my db, should i iterate the entire stacktrace, build a string and send it to my db..? it seems like too much

Comment: i saw this solution tough: StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
return errors.toString();

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `e.printStacktTrace()` will print a full stacktrace to the console. You can also get the exact line number with:

```
e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber();
```

The 0th element is the top of the stack. You can also use:

```
e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
```

to get the method.

Note that with some exceptions you'll need to head down the stack somewhat. Use `e.printStackTrace()` then.